# Program gives unexpected output -- why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program which will test arithmetic skills.
It is supposed to generate random questions, and give a random operation. 
Here is my code:

```
import random

score = 0
counter = 0
ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/']

def question():
    num1 = random.randint(0,10)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10) #Starts from 1 to avoid zerodivision error
    operation = random.choice(ops)
    question = float(input(f"What is {num1} {operation} {num2}?: "))
    global answer
    answer = eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2))
    global counter
    counter = counter + 1


def points():
    while counter < 10:
        question()
        if question == answer:
            print("\nCorrect!\n")
            global score
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print(f"\nWrong! The answer is {answer}\n")


points()

print(f"\nYou got {score} out of {counter}")
```

But it gives this output:

```
What is 9 + 3?: 12
Wrong! The answer is 12
```

It is supposed to say correct if the input matches the answer, and count a score, and print the score out of ten at the end.

Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in

```
if question == answer:
```

In that line, `question` is a reference to the **function** `question()` that you defined earlier. Since `answer` is some `int` holding the answer to the question, the `==` is always `False`. You never actually find out what the user typed in.

To fix that, do something like this:

```
def question():
    num1 = random.randint(0,10)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10) #Starts from 1 to avoid zerodivision error
    operation = random.choice(ops)
    user_answer = float(input(f"What is {num1} {operation} {num2}?: "))
    global answer
    answer = eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2))
    global counter
    counter = counter + 1

    return user_answer

def points():
    while counter < 10:
        user_answer = question()
        if user_answer == answer:
            print("\nCorrect!\n")
            global score
            score = score + 1
        else:
            print(f"\nWrong! The answer is {answer}\n")
```

I've changed the name to make it more clear what's going on.

---

As an addendum, I would highly, highly recommend not using global variables. They are almost never necessary and generally confuse the issue. For example, I think that

```
def question():
    num1 = random.randint(0,10)
    num2 = random.randint(1,10) #Starts from 1 to avoid zerodivision error
    operation = random.choice(ops)

    user_answer = float(input(f"What is {num1} {operation} {num2}?: "))
    real_answer = eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2))

    return user_answer, real_answer

def points():
    score = 0
    for questions_asked in range(1, 11):
        user_answer, real_answer = question()
        if user_answer == real_answer:
            print("\nCorrect!\n")
            score += 1
        else:
            print(f"\nWrong! The answer is {answer}\n")
```

This makes it much easier to understand the program flow.

Comment: At the line where is says: user_answer, real_answer = question() ... what did you do there?

Comment: @LaveenChandnani It's [tuple unpacking](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples#Packing_and_Unpacking).

Comment: so is it assigning user_answer and real_answer to the question() function? I don't understand where the question procedure is called in again on that?

Comment: `question()` is what calls the function named `question`. `user_answer` and `real_answer` are assigned to the output of `question()`, which is tuple containing the user answer and the real answer (the names match for consistency, but they don't have to).

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Your question has already been answered by Josh Karpel, but I just thought I'd point out another issue with division.

Division will always result in a `float` instead of an `int`, so if the user says `4 / 2` is `2`... the script will say the answer is wrong, because it's doing a stringy comparison of `"2"` with `"2.0"`. That's why in Josh's version, he converts the user answer to a `float`. This way the answers are compared numerically.

Additionally, the script is currently capable of asking things like `What is 4 / 7 ?` which is difficult for a person to answer. One work around would be to randomise `num2` until it is evenly divisible by `num1`.

```
def question():
    num1 = random.randint(0, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    operation = random.choice(ops)
    if operation == '/':
        while num1 % num2 != 0:
            num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    # do eval
```

Comment: Ah that clarifies some of it for me. Thank you